# Unable to import '@angular/common/http'

Tags: angular, http

I have tried many solutions thus far, but none worked. I am currently trying to import the HttpClient module from angular into my core module that would hold my angular services, but I am getting the following error: "Cannot find module '@angular/common/http'." whenever I try to import it.

I already installed the package using npm with "npm install @angular/http" and tried moving my import to app.module, but neither worked. It gives me this error in every file that I try to import it.

Here's my core.module file.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { SorterService } from './sorter.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers:[ DataService, SorterService]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

Comment: What is the version of the Angular you are using?

Comment: Hello, @yazantahhan. When I use "ng v" it prints out that my @angular/common (as well as my @angular/http) is at version 2.4.0.

Comment: seems you are using older version

Comment: Anyone knows how to update it? I tried ``npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` but it didn't do the trick apparently.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using an old version of Angular, you will need to use the `Http` services from `@angular/http` package and inject `Http` from the same package to send requests.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { SorterService } from './sorter.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers:[ DataService, SorterService]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

I really suggest to move to the newest if you don't have a reason to work with older.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, would you mind explaining how can I update it with npm?

Comment: You're welcome. This site is great to get the instructions when updating Angular from version to version: https://update.angular.io . If you just started and don't have an existing project, you can update the angular-cli globally using `npm install -g @angular/cli` and start a new project

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am currently trying to update via my packages with `ng update`. If this solves the problem, I'll mark your answer as accepted.